# Finding closed form of exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, exponential-function, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

> Let $S(n, k)$ be the Stirling number of the second kind. For a fixed
>   positive integer $k$, find a closed form for the exponential
>   generating function $B(x) = \sum_{n\ge0}S(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

I believe the closed form of

$$\sum_{n\ge0}n!\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

is $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but the inclusion of $S(n,k)$ confuses me.

Comment: Try for $k=1$ and $k=2$; this should give you an idea of the result.

Comment: Are you familiar with the exponential formula for generating functions In combinatorics? This is quite useful here

Answer (score 1):

Stirling numbers of the second kind, $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$, count the number of ways to divide a set of $n$ elements into $k$ classes. This gives, considering element $n$:

- **If $n$ is in a class by itself:** This leaves $n - 1$ elements to group into $k - 1$ classes, $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n - 1}{k - 1}$ ways to do this
- **If $n$ is in a class with other elements:** There are $n - 1$ other elements to divide into $k$ classes, $n$ can be in any one of them, $k \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n - 1}{k}$ ways

Pulling this together gives the recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k}
  &= \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n - 1}{k - 1} + k \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n - 1}{k}
\end{align*}$

As boundary conditions we have $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{0} = 0$ if $n > 0$, $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{n} = 1$.

To get an exponential generating function in $n$ for $\genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$,
call it $S_k(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k} \frac{z^n}{n!}$,
multiply the shifted recurrence by $z^n / n!$ and sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \ge 0} \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n + 1}{k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k - 1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
       + k \sum_{n \ge 0} \genfrac{\{}{\}}{0pt}{}{n}{k} \frac{z^n}{n!} \\
S_k'(z)
  &= S_{k - 1}(z) + k S_k(z)
\end{align*}$

From the boundary conditions we know $S_0(z) = 1$ and $S_k(0) = 0$ if $k > 0$.

The solution to the differential equation is:

$\begin{align*}
S_k(z)
  &= e^{k z} \int_0^z e^{-k t} S_{k - 1}(t) d t
\end{align*}$

This gives:

$\begin{align*}
S_0(z)
  &= 1 \\
S_1(z)
  &= e^z - 1 \\
S_2(z)
  &= \frac{(e^z - 1)^2}{2} \\
 S_3(z)
  &= \frac{(e^z - 1)^3}{3!} \\
S_4(z)
  &= \frac{(e^z - 1)^4}{4!}
\end{align*}$

Induction confirms that:

$\begin{align*}
S_k(z)
  &= \frac{(e^z - 1)^k}{k!}
\end{align*}$